# How to change the Owner a Group of a file using the terminal?

Tags: terminal, command

I'm trying to change the owner of a folder (myFolder) and all its content to **30061** with this line:

```
chown -Rv 30061 myFolder
```

But I get this message for some files

> chown: changing the owner of
>   myFolder/default/files/languages/es_smDXmy4sxGaYZuUOuV1ftDL7hg824v5FxIsQ2QqZcJM.js?:
>   Action denied

This files has the owner set to **20003**

If I try to change the permission with:

```
chmod -R 777 myFolder*
```

I get the same error message:

> chmod: changing permissions of
>   myFolder/default/files/languages/es_smDXmy4sxGaYZuUOuV1ftDL7hg824v5FxIsQ2QqZcJM.js?:
>   Action denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not the owner you'll need super-user rights. Prepend your command with a `sudo`, for example. Otherwise log in as root and run it as root.

Exception: immutable files.

Answer (score 1):

Modern Unix/Linux does not usually allow non-`root` users to "give away" files. In some cases, there's a kernel tunable to revert to older behavior and allow this, but it's usually not a good idea from a security standpoint. Either run the `chown` as `root`, or setup `sudo` to allow the necessary privilege escalation.